# Where is the contradiction in this fixed points proof?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

From Rotman's **Algebraic Topology**

> If $f \colon S^{2n} \rightarrow S^{2n}$, then either $f$ has a fixed point or some point is sent to its antipode.

The second half of the proof is as follows:

> Suppose that $f(x) \neq -x, \forall x \in S^{2n}$.  Define $g(x) = -f(x)$.  THen $g$ has no fixed points, and so $-f = g \simeq a^{2n}$, where $a^n$ represents the antipodal map.  Then $f \simeq -a^{2n} = 1_{S^{2n}}$ and $d(f) = 1$, a contradiction.

What does $d(f) = 1$ contradict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In his proof, Rotman shows first that $d(f)=-1$ by Theorem 6.23; this is what $d(f)=1$ contradicts.

Comment: Well, the contradiction actually arises from $-f \simeq a^{2n}$. Theorem 6.24 gives that in fact we have $f \simeq a^{2n}$, and applying Theorem 6.23 this gives $d(f)=1$. Note that in the proof of Theorem 6.25, the first line and a half is actually stating facts derived from 6.24 and 6.23; the assumption for contradiction comes afterwards.